# Using "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects" to Install FTDI Driver after Installation (Custom Action)

Tags: c#, installation, visual-studio-2019, ftdi

I have been trying to make an installer for my application and I cannot figure out how to successfully add FTDI driver installer.

The installer can be found at https://ftdichip.com/drivers/

I tried to add the installer as a file and include it under custom action (either Install or Commit). When I do so, the installer run correctly and FTDI installer pop up at the end, however regardless of what happens in the FTDI installer, the main installer gives the following error:
"There is a problem with this Windows Installer Package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor."

After some reading I realized that this could be due to FTDI driver not sending an exit code 0 upon completion. I wrote a simple script and the exit value was 1.

```
start /wait CDM212364_Setup.exe
echo %errorlevel%
```

I tried to make a wrapper in C# (a console application) to run the FTDI driver and mask the exist value but I could not find a way to integrate my console application to run add the end of the installation.

I have tried to read on the documentation for "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects" but it is rather limited and sometimes I do not fully understand it, since C# programming is not part of my daily routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the FTDI installer file in the application folder.
2. Add the installer project, then add install class 3. Override the `Commit` method with following code in the install class:

   ```
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start($@"{path}CDM212364_Setup.exe");
   ```

   `path` is a string passed from custom actions.

This works well for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am not currently working on the project and do not have the means to test this, so I am going to select this as the answer.